# Converting a bit to an int returns a negative value

Tags: t-sql, ssis-2012

I am trying to convert a bit field from the source DB into an integer value in the Data Warehouse in a SSIS Project (SQL Server 2012)

```
Select cast([MyField] as int) as TheField from MyTable
```

For some reason this returns 0 and -1, as opposed to the +1 I am expecting.
Even

```
Select abs(cast([MyField] as int)) as TheField from MyTable
```

will yield the -1 in the destination table. 
The SELECT statement works as intended in the preview as well as in SSMS and I see the desired 0 and 1. However the actual Data Transfer task in the SSIS Package isn't working as intended. I tried the data conversion task and a direct writing into the table without the task.

I really don't want to use an additional update statement to multiply my int values with -1.

As this may be a little confusing, here is the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empl](
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[active] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is the screenshot of the table:

[image]

And the screenshot of the data transfer task:

[image]

The destination table with the result of the Data transfer and conversion:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very interesting, if you put a data viewer you will see that downstream, MyField is either TRUE or FALSE, so what you can do is add a "derived column" component to create a new column with the expression:

`MyField ==  TRUE  ? 1 : 0`

then map this new column to the destination

Comment: Would this be faster than a subsequent SQL Statement Update table set field = field * (-1) ?  The only values I have are 0 and -1.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. This is the best solution.

Comment: the performance difference would be marginal, the only advantage of this solution is to be a bit (no pun intended :) neater since acts as a data conversion from TRUE/FALSE which are the actual values that will always be in the pipeline regardless the original value in myField

Comment: Very well, I will go with the derived column. It's still interesting how a "yes" value is converted into -1 instead of 1, but that's apparently a feature, not a bug :-)